# Post Json Data as Query String of a webrequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, web-services, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

In my scenario my API handles the json reading it as

```
if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)   
       {
            jsonData = context.Request.Params["key"]; 
       }
```

from my application how can i send a web request to this api without json as query string parameter. Sine Json is lengthy and i know query string is limited.

For android an ios this api works fine.

i have tried to add it to the header. but in vain.

how can i add it so that "jsonData = context.Request.Params["key"]; " will get my json.
my request format is here.

```
            urlS="http://abc.ashx?Key="+jsonRequestS;
            string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            var webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlS);
            webRequest1.Method = "POST";
            webRequest1.KeepAlive = false;
            webRequest1.ContentType =string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);//                
            Stream postDataStream1 = handler.GetPostStream(boundary,jsonRequestS);               // Writes boundary and files to memory stream.

            webRequest1.ContentLength = postDataStream1.Length;
            Stream reqStream1 = webRequest1.GetRequestStream();

            postDataStream1.Position = 0;

            var bufferBytes = new byte[postDataStream1.Length];
            postDataStream1.Read(bufferBytes, 0, bufferBytes.Length);
            reqStream1.Write(bufferBytes, 0, bufferBytes.Length);

            postDataStream1.Close();
            reqStream1.Close();

            var sReader = new StreamReader(webRequest1.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());//here Am getting the error.
            string resultS = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example request you'd like to use? You say you don't want to put json in the query string, then you say you want to read json from the query string.

Comment: "jsonData = context.Request.Params["key"]; This is the statement There in the api Which reads my Json Data.. I jst Want To Know how can i send the json to API so that API can read it. But as Qry string i can send a lengthy Json. So Which Method Should i use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for ur Reply.
I found a way to solve this.

Write the Json to the request stream with the header as

```
 postDataStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string header = string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Key\"\r\n\r\n");
            headerbytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(header);
            postDataStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
            headerbytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonRequestS);//writing json request.
            postDataStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
```

and at the server side it will be fine read in the statement

```
 jsonData = context.Request.Params["key"];
```